# Extract Text Formatted as JSON from Webpage

Tags: python, json

The API for the website Urban dictionary is a URL that takes you to a page that dumps out the json, see example here: http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=test

Is there a simple way to grab all the text on that page? Do I still need to use some type of HTML parser?

Comment: `import requests`
 and 
`text = requests.get("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=test").text`

Comment: @JacobIRR that's the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a command line tool such as curl

```sh
curl http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=test
```

For a python specific solution you could try a library such as [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests).

```
pip install requests
```

```py
import requests
data = requests.get(http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=test)
```

Comment: Requests was what I needed, see JacobIRR comment on my question. Thanks.